# login failed with WS Fed service

Tags: sharepoint, multi-tenant, ws-federation, wso2-identity-server

I missed something I thing during my test of IS.

I'm testing WSO2 IS (5.11.0) based on docker version.
I installed the application, configure some local user account, did some test with User portal.
No specific tenant, no ldap & co.
All is OK.

I configured some apache web server with SAML2 authentication, all works fine.

I try to configure WS Federation, with a Sharepoint service, and the login failed on the authentication step on the IS page.
I installed the test application PassiveSTSSampleApp, and I encounter exactly the same problem.

I put IS in debug mode, and I identified that the authentication failed because there is no tenant during the authentication step (tenant = null)
I tried with specifying the default tenant carbon.super with the login, and all works fine.

Why the WSFed didn't use the default tenant ?
Does I miss some parameters ?

Is it possible to specify a default tenant to WSFed SP ? 
Do you know how use tenant with sharepoint ? 
Because I don't find any information to do that.

regards

Comment: Do you have the passiveSTS sample in some tenant?

Comment: no, i don't have tenant configured on this test platform. All tests is directly configured on the main tenant.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by activating the option "Applications are by default restricted for usage by users of the service provider's tenant. If this application is SaaS enabled it is opened up for all the users of all the tenants." on the SP WS-Fed.